# DBMS_SCHEDULER job calls SP but doesn't update the date on each execution

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dbms-scheduler, sysdate

I'm creating a DBMS_SCHEDULER job that runs a stored procedure.
This procedure builds a report based on the input parameters, and the result is left in a file, like this:
Job:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(job_name            => 'REPORT',
                            job_type            => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                            job_action          => 'prc_report',
                            number_of_arguments => 1,
                            start_date          => Null,
                            repeat_interval     => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=1;BYHOUR=1', 
                            end_date            => Null,
                            enabled             => False,
                            auto_drop           => False);
DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(job_name          => 'REPORT',
                                            argument_position => 1,
                                            argument_value    => '25');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(Name => 'REPORT');
```

Stored procedure:

```
Create Or Replace Procedure prc_report(v_corte    In Varchar2)
(...)
If v_corte Like '%2%' Then
  v_fecha_inicio := To_Char(add_months(Sysdate, -1), 'YYYYMM') || '26';

  v_fecha_fin := To_Char(Sysdate, 'YYYYMM') || '25';
Else
  v_fecha_inicio := To_Char(trunc(add_months(Sysdate, -1), 'MM'),
                            'YYYYMMDD');

  v_fecha_fin := To_Char(last_day(add_months(Sysdate, -1)), 'YYYYMMDD');

End If;
```

The job that calls this code executes on the 26th of every month or on the 1st, based on the `v_corte` argument.

However, for whatever reason, when we go into the next month, `v_fecha_inicio` and `v_fecha_fin` do not get updated based on the current date. 
For instance, if I create the procedure and the job on October 10, 2018, the job will run on October 26, 2018, but when it runs on November 26, 2018 it seems it still takes the October 10, 2018, meaning the report will be created with the October 26, 2018 date.

I am not sure why this happens, it's like the date it stuck on the compilation date. The procedure is called and it runs without any errors, but date with which it runs is not updated on each execution.

The data inside the report uses the `v_fecha_inicio` and `v_fecha_fin`, so it's consistent with this error.

Any clues on what might be the issue?

Comment: You have not shown what variable finally goes into the report but `To_Char(add_months(Sysdate, -1), 'YYYYMM') || '26' ` definitely gives you `20181026` when run on any day in November

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak v_corte := '2' in this scenario, but it happens for both 1 and 2. The report has a range of dates, initial till final date. The one you used in your comment is for the initial date, so that's correct. This report should go from 20181026 to 20181125, but its dates are 20180926 to 20181026, even when the job runs every hour and should use today's month for calculating those dates.

Comment: It surely can't be taking the compile time date. But, I hope you are not confused about the  `add_months` function because `add_months(sysdate, -1)`surely takes the date back to previous month. Perhaps you wanted `add_months(sydate-1 ,1)`  ( subtract a date and add a month ) instead?

Comment: Hugo, Kindly let me know If the above comment fixes your problem, I may consider adding that as an answer and it may be helpful for others.